# show/hide icon on hover of input-generated list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a fiddle of my code (without the css styling) here: http://jsfiddle.net/X8bVr/

I'm trying to show a trash icon when a user hovers over a list input (dynamically generated from an input). Right now, the icon shows on hover, but doesn't go away on hover. Upon multiple mouseovers, it multiples the amount of icons on each list item.

I also want to make the trash icon a link that removes that specific list item.

Any other helpful tips towards optimizing my code is appreciated!

```
$(".input").click(function() {
if ($(this).val() == "Add task...") {
    $(this).val('');
}    
});

$('.input').keypress(function(event){

var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

if(keycode == '13' && $('.input').val().length != 0){
    var input = $(".input").val();
    var li = $("<li/>").text(input);
    $("#tasks").prepend(li);
    if ($(".input").val() != "Add task...") {
        $(".input").val('');
    }

    $("li").hover(function() {
        var trashIcon = $("<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>");

        $(trashIcon).appendTo($(this)).stop();
    }, function() {
        $(trashIcon).hide();
    });
}

});
```

Comment: I've edited my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X8bVr/1/
Now, the icon shows/hides properly, but it only shows/hides on the very first list item. How do I get it to show/hide on each specific li being moused over?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking mouseenter and mouseleave instead of hover:

1) Just add the icon on page load, and hide it

```
var trashIcon = $("<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>");
$(trashIcon).appendTo($(this)).stop();
$(trashIcon).hide();
```

2) Insted of hover, show icon when mouse enters li elements and hide when mouse gets out:

```
$("li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(trashIcon).show();
};
$("li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(trashIcon).hide();
};
```

Comment: @user2061806 you should follow the 1st point of @juvian but just load it on `enter keypress event` and not on page load.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very small mistake.The scope of `var trashIcon` is only when the mouse is on the `li` so this is the problem.

you can fix it in two ways

1. make `var trashIcon` global variable.
2. to the image use following code.

   ```
   $(this).find('.fa').hide();
   ```

hope this solves your problem.

---

**Edit :**

The `$(trashIcon)` is global hence when the next `li` is being appended the previous ones is being removed.

you can check it by `F12` elements.

So here is the solution to your problem.

Declare the

`var trashIcon = $("<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>");`

just before you register the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event

<kbd>[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/X8bVr/3/)</kbd> to explain more